# How to disable multiple buttons in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

My question is for example i have 3 buttons `(bt1,bt2,bt3)`. How can i simultaneously change their state without calling them by their proper names, using `btn[i]` or something?

Comment: why not put them in a list and iterate over?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `for` loop like this, which just takes all buttons and disables them in an easy to write way:

```
for x in (btn1, btn2, btn3):
    x.config(state = 'disabled')
```

I think this does what you want it to?

here is a full example:

```
import tkinter as tk
r = tk.Tk()

def disable_all():
    d.destroy()
    for z in (a, b, c):
        z.config(state = 'disabled')

def func(y):
    print('you clicked button ', y)

a = tk.Button(text = 'A', command = lambda: func('a'))
b = tk.Button(text = 'B', command = lambda: func('b'))
c = tk.Button(text = 'C', command = lambda: func('c'))
d = tk.Button(text = 'disable all', command = disable_all)

for x in (a, b, c, d):
    x.pack()

r.mainloop()
```

hope this helps!